# how do I use jquery widgets with grails?

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-plugin

I'm very new to grails, and I'm trying to create a simple interface and I'd like to use jQuery widgets.
I was planning on using just javascript, and not make use of tags for now.

So, do I need to install the plugin or is it better to just download jquery widget from their website?

If it's better to install the plugin even for that, how do I make it work? Do I only install this: compile ":jqueryui-widget:0.1.4.1" in buildConfig.groovy or do I need to do something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is *it depends*. It depends on how you intend on using the UI widgets.

If you want specific tag library support then you can use the plugin. If you don't want that, or some customized version of the widgets then you can include the libraries yourself.

The plugin does offer some additional functionality (resource resolution and taglib to mention two), but there is nothing stopping you from using the javascript libraries without the plugin.

As far as installing the plugin, you have done it correctly and you don't need to do anything else other than start using it in your code.

Comment: I actually tried installing the plugin, but when I try to do a simple  $("#mySelect").selectmenu(); I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". So I'm not sure if I'm installing the plugin correctly

Comment: and when I rebuild the app, I get a bunch of errors like: [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] C:\other_projects\ResourceReportTool\target\work\plugins\jqueryui-widget-0.1.4.1\grails-app\taglib\grails\jqueryui\widget\AccordionTagLib.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
  [groovyc]  @ line 3, column 1.
  [groovyc]    import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder
  [groovyc]    ^

Comment: Ah, those errors would indicate that that plugin isn't compatible with the latest 2.4.x version of Grails. ConfigurationHolder is no longer valid. Looks like you will have to use an older version of Grails or not use the plugin.

Comment: Or download plugin and fix this bug. Then make the patch and send to plugin author, or just write to him about bug.